# List is not being ordered

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have this exercise and despite of my attempt to implement the IComparable interface I can't sort the list by weight from least to most............................................................................

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Program
{
    abstract class Animal : IComparable<Animal>
    {
        private double weight;
        private int name;
        abstract public override string ToString();
        public int CompareTo(Animal right)
        {
            return weight.CompareTo(right.weight);
        }
    }
    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public Cat(double weight, string name)
        {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.name = name;
        }
        private double weight;
        private string name;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "I'm the cat " + name + " and I weight " + weight;
        }
    }
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Animal> myArray = new List<Animal>();
            for (int counter = 9; counter > 0; counter--)
            {
                myArray.Add(new Cat(counter * 3.5, counter.ToString()));
            }
            foreach (Animal CatOrDog in myArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CatOrDog.ToString());
            }
            myArray.Sort();
            foreach (Animal CatOrDog in myArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CatOrDog.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can try use `LINQ` `OrderBy` instead of sort to give some condition for the sort

Comment: The problem is that is an exercise about List and the IComparable interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the logic right, and it will sort correctly. However, your class definition is wrong:

```
abstract class Animal : IComparable<Animal>
{
    private double weight;
    private int name;
    abstract public override string ToString();
    public int CompareTo(Animal right)
    {
        return weight.CompareTo(right.weight);
    }
}
```

1. Both `weight` and `name` should be *protected*, not private, so that any subclass of `Animal` can read them.
2. `name` should be a `string`.

```
class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(double weight, string name)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name = name;
    }
    private double weight;
    private string name;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm the cat " + name + " and I weight " + weight;
    }
}
```

Remove the fields `weight` and `name` from `Cat`. Currently, they're hiding the fields, so you're assigning values to `Cat.weight`, but sorting on `Animal.weight`. Make these changes, and your code will work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, it was a mistake in my book. It instructed me to do the exercise by using private members in the abstract class.

Comment: @user3646717 If that's a requirement of the exercise, it would be possible: however the `Cat` constructor would have to call the `base` constructor, and not assign the fields itself. For example, `Cat` would only have `ToString()` and `public Cat(double weight, string name) : base(weight, name) { }`